# Why Can't I Assign Value to this Array in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm triying to find out the way i can know users are online on my App, therefore this data I'm saving it into text file, but when try reading line by line of the text file, I want to pass it into array to compare data better.
so here is how I doing it:

```
String folder = Application.StartupPath;
String file = "users.txt";

String str;
String[] strArray;
String[][] data;
int rows = 0;
StreamReader lines = new StreamReader(folder + file);
while ((str = lines.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    strArray = str.Split('~');
    for (int i = rows; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < strArray.Length; j++)
        {
            data[rows][j] = strArray[j]; // here is the error
        }
    }
    rows++;
}
```

As you see, I declared my array of data in before, but it says that it can't use it cause is unassigned.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "data" is never initialized. Your first for loop is useless. What error are you having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an explanation of the error, you need to look into jagged arrays. The key is that you need to initialize both the outer array and the inner arrays:

```
int[][] jagged = new int[5][];  // Initialized outer array
jagged[0] = new int[3];         // Initialized an inner array
```

However, since you don't know how many rows you need ahead of time, you should use a list instead:

```
List<List<String>> data = new List<List<String>>();
while ((str = lines.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    data.Add(str.Split('~').ToList());
}
```

Or, if you just want a single list:

```
List<String> data = new List<String>();
while ((str = lines.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    data.AddRange(str.Split('~'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't initializing the array with anything. Perhaps a `List<List<string>>` might be better.

Comment: This would still require the inner list to be created and added.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the array to have a null value and you're done

```
String[][] data = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved your code a bit. Also used List of String instead of array.

```
    String folder = Application.StartupPath;
    String file = "users.txt";
    String str;

    var strings = new List<string>();
    int row = 0;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(folder,file))
    {
    while ((str = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var splitArray = str.Split('~');
        foreach (var str in splitArray)
        {
         strings.Add(str);
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To create and fill an array, you will need to know the resulting size.  If you use LINQ and do the array creation as the last step, you can pull this off in a single statement:

```
var data = File.ReadLines(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "users.txt"))
               .Select(line => line.Split('~'))
               .ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String[][] data = new String[][];
```

you need to initialize it

Comment: Does that compile for you?